# Android vimeo video uploading

Tags: android, video, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

How to upload video using vimeo SDK `com.vimeo.networking:vimeo-networking`?
In the documentation and [example](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/tree/v1.1.0/example) project there is no example how to upload video. Also methods `VimeoClient.getInstance().putContent` and `VimeoClient.getInstance().postContent` are not documented. I've implemented method:

```
        VimeoClient.getInstance().postContent(videoUri, CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE, null, new ModelCallback<Video>(Video.class) {
        @Override
        public void success(Video video) {
            toast("Staff Picks Success! " + video);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(VimeoError error) {
            toast("Staff Picks Failure :( " + error);
        }
    });
```

but I'm receiving error when try to upload video. Here is stack trace

> W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: url == null
>   W/System.err:     at okhttp3.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:121)
>   W/System.err:     at retrofit2.RequestBuilder.build(RequestBuilder.java:204)
>   W/System.err:     at retrofit2.RequestFactory.create(RequestFactory.java:67)
>   W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.createRawCall(OkHttpCall.java:122)
>   W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:58)
>   W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.enqueue(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:57)
>   W/System.err:     at com.vimeo.networking.VimeoClient.POST(VimeoClient.java:1167)
>   W/System.err:     at com.vimeo.networking.VimeoClient.postContent(VimeoClient.java:1061)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vimeo Networking library you are referring to does not support upload; a separate upload library will be released at a later date. In order to upload you will need to follow the API [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos) yourself.

As the documentation states, it's a several step process. We have simplified the process down to 2 steps, however, it is not yet available to the public. Since there was no open sourced 4 step java library, we are not yet releasing the simplified java version until we open it up to the public, which is different than our [iOS counterpart](https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload#old-upload-new-upload).

Unfortunately for now you will need to follow those API docs if you wish to upload in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: https://github.com/clickntap/Vimeo
It is listed in the https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries