# Vimeo video upload from my android app

Tags: android, vimeo

How can I upload video from my android app to Vimeo.

1. I created Vimeo app.
2. Granted upload privilege.
3. Generated access token.
4. Checked quota available.

Now I want to upload video to vimeo, so please provide sample code to generating the ticket and to upload.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the [vimeo-networking](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java).

By doing so you'll import new pre-built (by vimeo) classes to your project that will handle all the authentication and data transfer between your android app and your `Vimeo app` you just created.

I would highly recommend to follow the step-by-step guide under the Github library.(If you having issues look under the Github issue tab because people probably had same problems already)

Comment: The vimeo-networking library does not currently handle upload. An upload specific library will be released at a later date, but for now, the process of uploading is manual.

Comment: Hi Kevin , how can we get the quota to upload video

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Vimeo Android library for you to use at the moment to assist in the upload process. For the public, it is currently a 4-step process to upload, outlined [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos). There is currently a 2-step process in closed beta. Once that is released to the public we will release an official Android library to support uploading to Vimeo. Unfortunately for now you must follow the API docs and make the requests yourself.

See a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311974/android-vimeo-video-uploading/38312335#38312335).