# How to upload video to vimeo from my android app? Is there any new library to implement that right now?

Tags: vimeo-android

Now, I'm developing android app that uploads video to vimeo from my android app. I'm new at Vimeo integration.
I would like someone to help me to implement that.

Is there any new library(Sample code or github) to satisfy that right now?

If there's any help, it will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is there is no official upload library (but we're working on one), and in the mean time you'll have to implement your own following the API documentation [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos).

There's a [networking library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java) that we offer that may help provide the models for the models the upload API will be using (like a `Video` and `User` object).

There are several posts on stack overflow that may help. Here is [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38699806/1759443).